# Shiny sliderInput behaviour change

Tags: user-interface, shiny, click, drag

While updating from shiny 0.13.2 to 1.0 I noticed the behavior of sliderInput controls has changed slightly and they now do not response to a click, but the cursor must now really be drag & drop (slide motion). Is there a way to go back to the old behavior where a click anywhere on the scale would automatically move the slider to that point? My sliderInput is relatively simple and looks like this:

```
sliderInput("slidername", NULL, min=0, max=100, value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for noting this. I've filed an issue on the Shiny Github repo (https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1605), so we can keep track of this. This behavior was probably introduced when we updated the ion range slider library (underlying library), and didn't notice this change. I don't know when/if we'll have the old behavior back though (depends on how much work it will be). Sorry...